# How can I convert the object array to GraphQL format in Javascript?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, graphql

I'm working with React, and I send this information:

```
const imageServicesClean = JSON.stringify(imageServices);
const query = `
    mutation {
        companyUpdate(
                idCompany:${idCompany},
                name:${nameClean},
                imageServices:${imageServicesClean})
            {
            idCompany
            name
            imageServices {
                idImageService
                name
                url
                key
            }
        }
    }`;
```

And the imageServicesClean is sent in this way, but return error:

```
[{
    "idImageService": 1,
    "name": "Service1",
    "url": "",
    "key": "asdasdas"
}, {
    "idImageService": 2,
    "name": "Service2",
    "url": "sdsads",
    "key": "sddsfsds_"
}]
```

Because my GraphQL server (Laravel) just allows the variable without quotes, in this way:

```
[{
    idImageService: 1,
    name: "Service1",
    url: "",
    key: "sdofunc4938urcnnwikk"
}, {
    idImageService: 2,
    name: "Service2",
    url: "sdsads",
    key: "sddsfsdssss8347yuirh"
}]
```

So the function `JSON.stringify` don't work for build format in GraphQL. How can I convert the object array to GraphQL format in Javascript?

Comment: how about using `JSON.parse(imageServices)` ?

Comment: `JSON.parse` takes a JSON string as argument, which is not the case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally this was my solution:

```
const imageServicesClean = JSON.stringify(imageServices);
const graphQLImageServices = imageServicesClean.replace(/"([^(")"]+)":/g,"$1:");
```

But finally I'm working with this library, it does everything for me: https://github.com/atulmy/gql-query-builder

Comment: Hi can i ask what the `(")` does? I thought this will be sufficient `/"([^"]+)":/g,"$1:"`, so i'm trying to understand what is the purpose of `(")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Albert reply. If you have `":` somewhere in your string like `"field": "\"Hello\": World"`, then after regexp replace you will end up with something like this: `field: "\\Hello\\: World"`.

I fixed this by adding `[^\\"]+` to the regexp, so it looks like

`imageServicesClean.replace(/"([^(")"]+[^\\"]+)":/g, "$1:");`

I am not quite sure if this is a right fix and do not causes any bugs, but it works for me for now