# How do I write a valid GraphQL mutation with a stringified nested object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, graphql

I've got a GraphQL schema for musical compositions which has an array of nested types for every instrument in the composition. The nested type includes the name of the instrument and a data field (defined as an array of bools).

How do I write the mutation in JS using a variable for the nested objects?

Below is what I've got using the nested types hardcoded to `[{instrument: "Bass", data: [true, false]}]`

```js
const obj = JSON.stringify([{instrument: "Bass", data: [true, false]}])

const query = `mutation {
  createComposition(
    compositionInput: {
      recording: ${obj}
    }
  ){
    shortid
  }
}`

const body = JSON.stringify({ query })

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body
}

fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.errors) console.log(res.errors)
    else console.log(res.data)
  })
```

This fails with `Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "instrument"`. Here's the full query body for the request:

```
{"query":"mutation {\n      createComposition(\n        compositionInput: {\n          recording: [{\"instrument\":\"Bass\",\"data\":[true,false]}]\n        }\n      ){\n        shortid\n      }\n    }"}
```

The double stringify seems to be the problem causing escaped quotes on the nested object properties, but I don't know how else to do it.

Using string interpolation with the raw object turns it into ye olde `[object Object]` and if I hardcode the object directly into the string (bypassing the first stringify call) it works fine, but I want the object to be variable.

I've found this solution [How can I convert the object array to GraphQL format in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614730/how-can-i-convert-the-object-array-to-graphql-format-in-javascript) but the answer is to regex out the double quotes generated by the first stringify. That feels like a hack.

It seems like it shouldn't be this hard and if it is I'd imagine it'd be a common problem. Could I be doing this totally wrong? Any ideas?

Here's the entire schema definition:

```
  type Composition {
    _id: ID!
    recording: [InstrumentRecording!]!
    created: String!
    modified: String!
    shortid: String!
  }

  input CompositionInput {
    recording: [InstrumentRecordingInput!]!
  }

  type InstrumentRecording {
    instrument: String!
    data: [Boolean!]!
  }

  input InstrumentRecordingInput {
    instrument: String!
    data: [Boolean!]!
  }

  type Query {
    compositions: [Composition!]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    createComposition(compositionInput: CompositionInput): Composition
  }

  schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
  }
```

Comment: JSON syntax != GraphQL syntax. You shouldn't use interpolation to provide dynamic values to your query. [Use variables instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924792/template-literal-getting-error-from-api/57926450#57926450).

Comment: Thank you, I understand that the syntax isn't equivalent but for the life of me I couldn't come up with the right search terms to find a solution to this. It looks like variables are the answer, trying to get it to work now.